# Can I force SSL to secure a Dotnetnuke Module Edit Page?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have a DNN modules where I don't care if the **VIEW page does not use SSL**.

However, when a module editor loads **my modules' EDIT page** in the admin template (my module is the only module on the page) I want to load the page securely using SSL, if the site has SSL capability.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just put the following at the start of the modules's code behind.

```
// Force Page to use SSL if it can.
if (PortalSettings.SSLEnabled && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
  DotNetNuke.Security.PortalSecurity.ForceSecureConnection();
}
```